# Straightforward way to implement custom drawn NSMenuItem views

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, nspopupbutton

I would like to have a `NSMenu` with several `NSMenuItem`s in it. Those items shall behave just like "normal" `NSMenuItem`s, with one exception: I would like to be able to draw the *contents* (i.e. the "foreground") of each item on my own.

That is:

- I would like **the operating system** to draw the blue highlight when I hover with the mouse, draw the checkmark or dash (to signify "selected"/"part of multi-selection"). Moreover, I would like "normal", i.e. menu-built-in mouse/keyboard behaviour.
- I would like to draw the "contents" **myself**: Ideally, I would imagine that I would have to implement/override one single method `drawMenuItem:withCGContext:inRectangle:withTextColor`, which basically obtains the item, the `CGContext` to draw into, the `NSRect` of the item, and the text color *that would be used by Mac OS* if it drew the item itself.

I know (suspect very stronlgy) that my wish is probably too much, but I would be perfectly fine with something adequate (e.g. I could imagine fetching the `NSRect` from the `NSMenuItem` myself, obtaining the color using something like `[NSColor selectedMenuItemTextColor]`, and the context using something like `[NSContext currentContext]`).

Of course I considered [Apple's instruction on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ViewsInMenuItems.html). However, doing this prevents the menu from drawing the blue highlight background and the check mark. Moreover, as far as I could see, I would have to implement e.g. `mouseUp` myself.

To sum it up: Is there a way to get a (almost) fully functional menu, where I only customize the contents where usually the menu item title goes (possibly even without custom views)?

Comment: Can't you set the image of the menu item?

Comment: @Willeke I thought about this, but was somewhat hesitant since I do now know whether that's what the image originally was conceived for. Moreover, I was not sure whether it is straightforward to change the foreground color dynamically, based on the "highlight" state of the `NSMenuItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: No.

Since you are replacing the entire view of the menu item you are responsible for the drawing and to handle the events.

Comment: Your answer is probably true. But couldn't it be that I possibly do not have to use a custom view in the first place? I was hoping that there is some technique, possibly without a custom view, to acchieve what I am after.

Comment: Unfortunately `NSMenuItem` inherits from `NSObject` so there is no (public) view related API to override.

Comment: True, and I observed in the view hierarchy debugger that an `NSMenu` with plain vanilla items does not contain subviews for each item, but instead seems to draw everything in the `NSView` of the whole menu. So I thought: "maybe I could subclass this one..."

Comment: I saw that you can install an image for an `NSMenuItem`. Couldn't I e.g. just use an image filling the whole item?

Comment: Yes you can, but the layout constraints are predefined that the image is displayed on the left side next to the text field. Just try it.